# Autocomplete Jquery does not shows the results

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I using [Jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and I have the following code:

Client side:

```
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "get_professionals",
            data: request,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                alert("hello");
            }
        });
    }  
});
```

Server side:

```
function get_professionals() {
    if ($_POST["term"]):
        $professionals = Professional::find('all', array('conditions' => "name LIKE '%" . $_POST["term"] . "%'"));
        foreach ($professionals as $professional):
            echo $professional->to_json();
        endforeach;  
    endif;
}
```

the URL is right and, in fact, I get the results from server(I checked it from Firebug in "post" tab) but does not shows

Comment: use `response` as callback of AJAX success, or forget your own ajax and just pass URL as value for `source`. See demos

Comment: I'm not sure you're converting the list of professionals correctly into JSON.  Lists need to look like `[ {}, {}, {} ]` not `{} {} {}`

Comment: What does the data coming from the server look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The autocomplete requires a `label` and/or `value` field to be returned in the data.](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

> > Array: An array can be used for local data. There are two supported formats:
> >
> > An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
> >
> > **An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]**
> >
> > The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the label.

Adjust your query to return what you want in the autocomplete in `value` and/or `label` fields.

```
SELECT name AS label, id AS value from professionals.....
```

Or, some other method to return values like the bolded example from the documentation above. For example, you could set the `label` and `value` fields in the success function:

```
success: function(data) {
    response($.map(data, function(item) {
        return {
                label: item.name,
                id: item.id
                };
        }));
      }
```